# Need Help Making Outlook account creator using selenium python and 2captcha - Funcaptcha

Tags: python, selenium, 2captcha

Stuck On the Captcha Solving was trying to use a project called unicode if someone could help me on this part it would be appreciated
Using 2Captcha

Other Than that everything else is working for me to create the accounts , just this one small issue that I simply cannot figure out

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from twocaptcha import TwoCaptcha
from unicaps import CaptchaSolver,CaptchaSolvingService

#import email list
email_list = []
emails = open('email-creation-list.txt', 'r')
endOfFile = False
while endOfFile == False:
    temp = emails.readline().strip()
    if not temp:
        endOfFile = True
    else:
        email_list.append(temp)
print((email_list))
cycle = 0

x = 1
while x == 1:
    #main
    GChrome = webdriver.Chrome()
    GChrome.get('https://signup.live.com/signup')
    time.sleep(4)
    GChrome.find_element_by_link_text("Get a new email address").click()
    time.sleep(3)
    box_login = GChrome.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="MemberName"]')
    box_login.click()
    box_login.send_keys(email_list[cycle])
    time.sleep(3)
    box_login = GChrome.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="MemberName"]').send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    time.sleep(3)
    box_password = GChrome.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="PasswordInput"]')
    box_password.click()
    box_password.send_keys('kPb8nzbckquxSa')
    box_password = GChrome.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="PasswordInput"]').send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    time.sleep(2)
    firstname = GChrome.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="FirstName"]')
    firstname.click()
    firstname.send_keys('John')
    lastname = GChrome.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="LastName"]')
    lastname.click()
    lastname.send_keys('Doe')
    lastname = GChrome.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="LastName"]').send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    time.sleep(2)

    s = Select(GChrome.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="BirthDay"]'))
    # select by option index
    s.select_by_index(4)
    time.sleep(2)

    s2 = Select(GChrome.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="BirthMonth"]'))
    s2.select_by_index(4)

    month = GChrome.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="BirthYear"]')
    month.click()
    month.send_keys('1997')
    month = GChrome.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="BirthYear"]').send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    time.sleep(2)


#unicaps
    solver = CaptchaSolver(CaptchaSolvingService.TWOCAPTCHA, api_key='')
    solver.get_balance()
    solver = solver.solve_funcaptcha('B7D8911C-5CC8-A9A3-35B0-554ACEE604DA','https://signup.live.com/signup')


   # solved = solver.solve_funcaptcha(
   # public_key='B7D8911C-5CC8-A9A3-35B0-554ACEE604DA',
    #page_url='https://signup.live.com/signup'
    #)

    time.sleep(10)
```

**Other information**

- Used - Time,Selenium,2Capctha,Unicaps(please let me know if you know how to use this or an alternative)
- 2Captcha Python API - https://pypi.org/project/2captcha-python/ - Kinda New to python so its not any use for me

Comment: Instead of adding additional random text to the end of your question to get around the quality filter, please instead add additional information that could benefit or further clarify your question.

Comment: sorry wasnt sure what else to add

Comment: @DavidS Were you able to break Funcaptcha using 2captcha ?